# Regex to match <a> tags that do not contain specific URL query

Tags: regex, html-parsing, query-string

I need a regex that will select all `<a>` tags that do not contain a specific query. For example here is a list of a tags:

```
<!-- valid -->
<a href="testsite.com">Test Content</a>
<a href="testsite.com?source=facebook">Test Content</a>
<a href="testsite.com?test=123">Test Content</a>
<a href="testsite.com/path/morepath">Test Content</a>

<!-- invalid (query string is test=abc) -->
<a href="testsite.com?test=abc">Test Content</a>
```

How do I write a regex that only select links that ***do not*** have a query string of `test=abc`. I have searched all over Stack Overflow and, while I understand the concept of negative lookaheads/lookbehinds, I cannot seem to get it to work.

I am developing a custom RSS feed that will be used to promote content on a third party website. I am using the WordPress loop to pull in the content, dynamically finding links that belong to our website and adding query strings. When that is done I need to find all of the links that do not have the query string so I can strip tags per the requirements of the third party website. I hope this provides a little more insight into this.

Comment: Hi @Cory, when formatting code, make sure you put some new lines between your paragraphs and your code so it formats correctly. Corys have to stick together, so I got your back this time :)

Comment: First post on Stack Overflow. I tried to clean it up a little bit. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Could you add which language/technologies you're using? Regular expressions, in my opinion, may not be the right solution here. Also, welcome to [so]!

Comment: In general, regexes are not a good tool for parsing HTML.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes for some examples of HTML code that will not be found by most regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
<a href="(?![^>]*?test=abc">[^"]*?>)[^"]*">([^<]+)<\/a>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ8qO9/1).